# How do I improve handling of if/else local variables?

Tags: c++

I commonly have code where I want to detect some condition, and if it exists, then process that condition.

The test for the condition extracts certain information that is important to the processing half of the problem.

However, if/else constructs fail to allow one to declare local-to-the-if variables in the if construct itself(1).  Hence, I have to put variable declarations before the beginning of the entire if/else chain for all of the various conditions for which information may be extracted.

For example:

```
    else if ((EndsWithToken("d") || EndsWithToken("dsh")) &&
             (p1 = find(m_input_line, '[')) &&
             (p2 = find(m_input_line, ']')) &&
              p2 > p1)
    {
                // process what we found inside of the [ ] brackets using p1 and p2...
            }
```

This snippet is part of a long chain of if/else's, and the others don't need p1 and p2 - but they might need an integer value that was extracted from the input stream, or a double, or two points, or whatever....

The point is, there is no way that I know of introduce const TCHAR * p1 and p2 locally to the above scope, the only place it is used, that still allows for the overall structure to remain the same.

Is there some C++ language feature or a pattern that might allow for this?

---

(1) As some have pointed out, it is possible to declare a single variable of fundamental type, if it is the fist thing, and to test it against non-zero only.  This is far too limited to be of much use as a general solution to this issue (though the occasional moment could come up where it is useful - but truly rare).

Comment: Although this does not directly answer your question, you can drop `p2` altogether by searching to the right of `p1`, like this: `if ((EndsWithToken("d") || EndsWithToken("dsh")) && (p1 = find(m_input_line, '[')) && find(p1, ']'))`

Comment: Thanks - but in a case like this the point is to both test for square brackets, and to test that they occur in the correct order [], not ][, and to extract their location in the input string so that the text inside the brackets can be analyzed.  It's purely an efficiency thing: it just feels wrong to me to execute the code to find the position of these symbols, but then forget them and recompute them a second (or third) time.  Honestly, I find that C/C++ could use the ability to declare variables similarly to a for loop in more places, and more flexibly. ah well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to make each case a distinct function, that returns whether or not it succeeded.

This gives you a natural well-localized scope for the variables, and hopefully (assuming) a reasonable compiler can inline them.

Comment: Maybe with lambda functions I could do that without creating a ton of named functions at the class scope...

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to define local variables in `if` and `while` statements; however, you can only declare a single one per statement, and you can only test the value for non-zero:

```
...
else if (TCHAR *p1 = find(m_input_line, '['))
{
    if (TCHAR *p2 = find(m_input_line, ']'))
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this case, you could also just declare `TCHAR *p1, *p2;` before the chain of `if`/`else` statements, I wouldn't see any problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not true. You can declare a variable to the scope of the `if` if you initialize it there.

```
if ( int i = 0 )
{
    i = 1;
}
else
{
    i = 2;
}
```

This is a dumbed-down example, but it's legal.

Comment: Well, yes, that does work.  But I need at least two variables.  I suppose I could use a pair or something similar...

Comment: NOPE. :(  This fails to compile - various attempts using std::pair<> and auto + make_pair.

Comment: @Mordachai yes, but the main point was that you *can* declare a variable with the scope of the `if`.

Comment: You could put all of the return values into a single structure, and return that; if the structure has an implicit conversion to `bool`, it would work as above.  IMHO, though, it's still a hack (this is one feature of the standard that I would never use), and I'd look at some other forms of functional decomposition, or perhaps something using polymorphism, rather than write such complicated functions.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to unwind's answer: what about using inline functions for the body of the if/then/else?

However, I guess in both cases you might need to pass quite some values.

Comment: Yes - getting enough context across can be very problematic.  I'd need them to all be member functions. But maybe with lambdas.

Comment: Not sure if that is nice style, but of course you could use a "functional object", i.e. make all the local vars of your function member vars, and then distribute your function's logic over the methods. Not sure if that will produce readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Extract into a function.

```
bool validate(const string& line){
   auto startIndex = line.find('[');      
   auto endIndex = line.find(startIndex,']');
   return startIndex != -1 && endIndex != -1 && endIndex > startIndex;
}

//....
else if( EndsWith({"d","dsh"}) && validate(m_input_line) ){ ...}
```

I notice the prefix "m_" so I am guessing this is part of some class. So make private helper functions as necessary to make the code cleaner and easier to understand.